# OVER or IN the period/periods given?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> 1999: travels-50
>
> 2000: travels-60
>
> "The figure for travels increased *over* the period/periods given."

When it comes to the "over" in the sentence, is this a grammatically correct sentence? I am confused because I am not sure which preposition to use. **Over/in**

Answer (score 2):

Both can be correct, but there is a difference in meaning between them.  The term "over the period" explicitly distributes the event across the time, while "in the period" allows the event to happen all at once.

> 1. Over a period of 10 years, the gambler lost a hundred thousand dollars.

In this sentence the loss will happen throughout the time frame.

> 2. The detective concluded that the break in occurred in the period between 8am and noon time.

Here the event happens all at once, or for only a portion of the time.

Comment: Is "increased" + "over" grammatical?

Comment: Sure. "The global temperature has increased over the past decade."

Comment: Not like that, I mean no auxillaries, just plain "increased".

Comment: @JohnArvin Again, sure. "The temperature increased over a short period of time."